# Possible to trigger an event when user changes system date and time on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to trigger an event when the user changes the system date and time on iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW44)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on a non-jailbroken device.